# does ubuntu 11.10 is support ns2.29

Tags: wireless

I need your help, I'm a beginner on NS2 , and I'm trying to install ns2.29 on ubuntu 11.10 32bits but i can't. This message appear and installation stopped :

```
Build tcl8.4.11
============================================================
loading cache ./config.cache
checking whether to use symlinks for manpages... no
checking whether to compress the manpages... no
checking whether to add a package name suffix for the manpages... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for building with threads... no (default)
checking if the compiler understands -pipe... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -pipe -E
checking for sin... no
checking for main in -lieee... yes
checking for main in -linet... no
checking for net/errno.h... no
checking for connect... yes
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking how to build libraries... static
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking if 64bit support is requested... no
checking if 64bit Sparc VIS support is requested... no
checking system version (for dynamic loading)... ./configure: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
tcl8.3.2 configuration failed! Exiting ...
Tcl is not part of the ns project. Please see www.Scriptics.com
to see if they have a fix for your platform.
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: "Please see www.Scriptics.com to see if they have a fix for your platform." ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, in some of the configure scripts the calls to awk are malformed.

- Go to the `ns-allinone` folder and type

  ```
  find . -name configure
  ```

A list of the configure scripts should appear.

- For each of these replace any line that looks like this:

  ```
  system=MP-RAS-`awk ‘{print }’ /etc/.relid’`
  ```

  with ...

  ```
  system=MP-RAS-`awk ‘{print }’ /etc/.relid`
  ```

Now rerun `./install` in the `ns-allinone` folder.

[Source](http://old.nabble.com/Installation-problem-of-allinone-2.29-on-Kubuntu-8.04-td19989633.html)